# Pine Script How to find highest equity?

Tags: pine-script

```
highestEquity = ta.highest(strategy.equity, bar_index + 1)
```

I'm trying to find the highest equity from as far back as possible to the present but when I run the code above, I get this error.

> **Study Error**
> Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series.
> Try using max_bars_back in the study or strategy function.

I'm not familliar with using `max_bars_back()`, how do I use it to find the highest equity? Is there a workaround to finding the highest equity without getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pine script sometime the no of bars back reference need to be defined.
your have to add max_bars_back=1000 in the main strategy() function. (1000 is just a example you can put any number less than 5000 as per your requirements )

Example

```
strategy('Script', overlay=true, max_bars_back=500)
```